# Quantum mechanics limits to understanding the Universe

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem, determinism

By definition, a wave function does not describe a particle's state *exactly*, we can only know that information when we make measurements and thus collapse the wave function.

This gives us a lot of interesting counter-intuitive facts such as the Shrödinger's cat being 50% dead and alive at the same time until we open the box to measure, or that a particle that's expected to be found here when measured could, with extremely little chance, be found on the Moon instead.

*The way I see it*, quantum mechanics is just a model that tries to move humanity forward in understanding the Universe. In other words, given the Uncertainty Principle limiting our ability to measure the small stuff, quantum mechanics tries to circumvent that limitation. But in doing so we start to see a lot of absolutely counter-intuitive but most importantly *unreasonable* conclusions with quantum mechanics, such as the undead cat, the fact that we don't experience a wave function on a macroscopic level, etc. (note when I say "unreasonable" I mean the opposite to conclusions that are counter-intuitive but absolutely understandable with reason like time relativity, which also happens to be proved).

I like to think that there *is* a specific state for the Universe at all times, and I believe the wave function does not forbid that but rather is a limited approach to understanding the Universe given the limitations imposed by the Uncertainty Principle.

My question is: could it be that reality actually has a specific state but we simply cannot measure it and we rely on less than perfect models to move forward in our understanding of the Universe? In other words, could it be that the absurd conclusions of the undead cat and the particle on the Moon are actually impossible but quantum mechanics fail to set limits on that?

Comment: I suggest you read up on Bell's theorem. The predictions of QM can be distinguished from the predictions of any deterministic and causal theory.

Comment: @puppetsock To be fair, I think saying that "deterministic and causal" theories are eliminated might be going a bit too far. Certainly deterministic and _local_ theories are eliminated, and it's also fairly commonplace for the definition of causality to rely on locality, but are you certain that there isn't some nonlocal form of causality that still works?

Comment: Hi. You basically ask if there is a model or not that could predict something more than what quantum mechanics predict, and that prediction is based on an assumption or aesthetic of how the universe could be. It is not a valid question- I believe- of whether or not a perfect model exists because even as a concept we cannot agree what that would mean. Even so, it is possible that no perfect model exist because the universe is not perfect under the standards you assume and is more than perfect from another viewpoint. Thank you but I find the question illogical at least.

Comment: @probably_someone  Am I certain that nonlocal theories can't work? Pretty sure since you lose an initial value problem and so can't predict the results of experiments.

Comment: There are no perfect models in physics. However, a desire for the universe to be deterministic is a psychological obsession based on human insecurity. It has no scientific justification.

Comment: @puppetsock A system can be described in coordinates different from space and time. If you have a map of causes and results, even if non local, you could use this map as a coordinate system, in which the system description is consistent despite the non locality. In this case, the fact that you cannot locally predict the results of an experiment is only your technical limitation that does not create a contradiction for the theory.

Comment: "By definition, a wave function does not describe a particle's state *exactly*". This is wrong. Pretty much by definition, a wave function (aka quantum *state*) completely describes the state of a system. The *exactness* that you find missing has just no meaning in quantum mechanics.

Comment: @safesphere: I did not realise I am violating the rules. If that is so (as you said), can my comments be deleted by a moderator? Are the trajectory results uncertain, or they appear to be? What happens to the overall trajectory? Does it fall in place overall? meaning does it come back to the expected, or it becomes totally random overall. If it knows how to come back to the normal, I do not think there was any uncertainty, may be it just took a different path. I think uncertainty in trajectory (without correction in overall) would wreck havoc at macro level.

Comment: @kpv I've deleted my comment. On the trajectory, I recall a double slit experiment with heavy atoms of cesium detected at the slits by microwave photons. The momentum of these photons was way too small to affect the trajectory of the atoms. However the interference lines completely disappeared with these photons present. Thus what matters is the fact of the measurement, but the measurement does not create uncertainty. The uncertainty is there as the nature of things. It can be viewed as a property of waves. Here is a pretty good illustration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBnnXbOM5S4

Comment: @safesphere: Watching. S/he is the person moving the stick, an observer. Can you delete my comments too? Thanks

Comment: @safesphere: Deleted, thanks for letting me know, Do not having tried to delete comments before, but edit is allowed only for 5 minutes and assumed same for delete.

Answer (score 2):

Mainstream physics is based on the underlying framework out of which all classical theories arise as quantum mechanical. This has not deterred people from working on non local theories that will give the same prediction as quantum mechanics but be deterministic.

Two such come to mind,[Bohmian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory) and the model [Gerald 'd Hooft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerard_%27t_Hooft#Fundamental_aspects_of_quantum_mechanics) is working with. The latter participated for a time in discussions here and you will be able to find them searching the users, on the left .

The mainstream research follows the classical Copenhagen interpretation. BTW the cat being dead or alive is a bad example of using a live animal instead of a Geiger counter in the decay of particles. The poor cat is just an extension of whether the counter gave a hit , or not.